# Shortest way between two points by going through all other points from point collection

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry, distance

Given a point collection defined by x and y coordinates.

In this collection I get the start point, the end point and all the other n-2 points.

I have to find the shortest way between the start point and end point by going through all the other points. The shortest way is defined by its value and if possible the crossing point order.

At a first look this seems to be a graph problem, but i am not so sure about that right now, any way i am trying to find this shortest way by using only geometric relations since currently all the information that i have is only the x and y coordinates of the points, and which point is the start point and which is the end point.

My question is, can this way be found by using only geometric relations?

I am trying to implement this in C#, so if some helpful packages are available please let me know.

Comment: What does "crossing point order" mean? Is this just the [Travelling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)?

Comment: The "crossing point order" means the order in which the points are added to the minimal way. For instance these points can be keeped in a collection and first two points are defining the shortest way between first two points, then the third point from collection is defining the shortest way between the second and third point, and so on.

Comment: Yes, it is allowed to visit a point more than once.

Comment: How many points are there? Is an approximate solution OK? Are you willing to use other people's software?

Comment: Somehow either I don't understand the question properly or the title really has almost nothing to do with the problem. Do you want a *single line* that goes as close as possible (for some definition of closeness) past all the points or a tour in the form of a polyline?

Comment: My initial title was modified, the end result is a polyline which should start from start point, move through all the other points, and stop in the end point.

Comment: Theoretically there can be an unlimited number of points, but no more than 25 points i think that are quite enough. An approximate solution is not ok... the minimal polyline which is going through all the points is needed, or at least its length. I should solve this by using only .NET 4.5 framework.

Comment: Well @Placeholders_in_use's edit was clearly invalid, I rolled it back.

Comment: @MirceaLucian So you're saying you always have at most 25 points? Because than you might consider using an exponential time DP solution (O(n * 2^n) or something)

Comment: Thank you Niklas B. for rolling back the title :), and support, yes there will be no more than 25 points. Somehow the code complexity will not be an issue, any way this algorithm seems to be more chalenging than i though before :).

Comment: @MirceaLucian I added a description of the exponential-time algorithm I had in mind, which I think will work very well for your scale (it should hardly take longer than a few seconds for n = 25).

Comment: That is a good time ! Thank you for the update ! I will soon start doing the implementation. Probably tommorow now... is almost mid night, and i am geeting sleepy... Thank you again for helpful sugestions !

Comment: It was valid, if you were looking to draw a line like an HR across the screen, which I thought you were trying to do.  Also your question wasn't phrased in the form of a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest heuristic with reasonable performance is 2-opt. Put the points in an array, with the start point first and the end point last, and repeatedly attempt to improve the solution as follows. Choose a starting index i and an ending index j and reverse the subarray from i to j. If the total cost is less, then keep this change, otherwise undo it. Note that the total cost will be less if and only if d(p[i - 1], p[i]) + d(p[j], p[j + 1]) > d(p[i - 1], p[j]) + d(p[i], p[j + 1]), so you can avoid performing the swap unless it's an improvement.

There are a possible number of improvements to this method. 3-opt and k-opt consider more possible moves, resulting in better solution quality. Data structures for geometric search, kd-trees for example, decrease the time to find improving moves. As far as I know, the state of the art in local search algorithms for TSP is Keld Helsgaun's [LKH](http://www.akira.ruc.dk/~keld/research/LKH/).

Another family of algorithms is branch and bound. These return optimal solutions. [Concorde](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde.html) (as far as I know) is the state of the art here.

Here's a Java implementation of the O(n^2 2^n) DP that Niklas described. There are many possible improvements, e.g., cache the distances between points, switch to floats (maybe), reorganize the iteration so that subsets are enumerating in increasing order of size (to allow only the most recent layer of `minTable` to be retained, resulting in a significant space saving).

```
class Point {
    private final double x, y;

    Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    double distanceTo(Point that) {
        return Math.hypot(x - that.x, y - that.y);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return x + " " + y;
    }
}

public class TSP {
    public static int[] minLengthPath(Point[] points) {
        if (points.length < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int n = points.length - 2;
        if ((1 << n) <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        byte[][] argMinTable = new byte[1 << n][n];
        double[][] minTable = new double[1 << n][n];
        for (int s = 0; s < (1 << n); s++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int sMinusI = s & ~(1 << i);
                if (sMinusI == s) {
                    continue;
                }
                int argMin = -1;
                double min = points[0].distanceTo(points[1 + i]);
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    if ((sMinusI & (1 << j)) == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    double cost =
                        minTable[sMinusI][j] +
                        points[1 + j].distanceTo(points[1 + i]);
                    if (argMin < 0 || cost < min) {
                        argMin = j;
                        min = cost;
                    }
                }
                argMinTable[s][i] = (byte)argMin;
                minTable[s][i] = min;
            }
        }
        int s = (1 << n) - 1;
        int argMin = -1;
        double min = points[0].distanceTo(points[1 + n]);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            double cost =
                minTable[s][i] +
                points[1 + i].distanceTo(points[1 + n]);
            if (argMin < 0 || cost < min) {
                argMin = i;
                min = cost;
            }
        }
        int[] path = new int[1 + n + 1];
        path[1 + n] = 1 + n;
        int k = n;
        while (argMin >= 0) {
            path[k] = 1 + argMin;
            k--;
            int temp = s;
            s &= ~(1 << argMin);
            argMin = argMinTable[temp][argMin];
        }
        path[0] = 0;
        return path;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point[] points = new Point[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            points[i] = new Point(Math.random(), Math.random());
        }
        int[] path = minLengthPath(points);
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(points[path[i]]);
            System.err.println(points[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your algorithm proposal i will soon start implement it  and see how is behaving ! Peviously i was just calculating the shortest distance from each point to all the other points and then that distance was added to the final result. Still doing things like that was not giving in the end the shortest way through all the points.

Comment: My mistake, the algorithm I had in mind is O(2^n * n^2) too, so not necessarily a matter of seconds without heavy micro-optimizations

Answer (score 4):

The [Euclidean travelling salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Euclidean_TSP) problem can be reduced to this and it's NP-hard. So unless your point set is small or you have a very particular structure, you should probably look out for an approximation. Note that the Wikipedia article mentions the existence of a [PTAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme) for the problem, which could turn out to be quite effective in practice.

**UPDATE:** Since your instances seem to have only few nodes, you can use a simple exponential-time dynamic programming approach. Let f(S, p) be the minimum cost to connect all the points in the set S, ending at the points p. We have f({start}, start) = 0 and we are looking for f(P, end), where P is the set of all points. To compute f(S, p), we can check all potential predecessors of p in the tour, so we have

```
f(S, p) = MIN(q in S \ {p}, f(S \ {p}, q) + distance(p, q))
```

You can represent S as a bitvector to save space (just use an single-word integer for maximum simplicity). Also use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to avoid recomputing subproblem results.

The runtime will be O(2^n * n^2) and the algorithm can be implemented with a rather low constant factor, so I predict it to be able to solve instance with n = 25 within <strike>seconds</strike> a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: So in the end, this has to be a graph problem and i should stop trying to solve it, in a simpler geometrical way ?

Comment: @MirceaLucian Well no, it's not really a graph problem. Euclidean TSP is way "easier" in a certain sense than the TSP problem in general graphs, as evidenced e.g. by the existence of a PTAS which exploits geometric properties as well as graph-related concepts. The simple factor-2 approximation uses minimum spanning trees and the triangle inequality. Both need some adaption because you don't need the tour to return to the starting point

Comment: I assume that you're referring to Arora's PTAS. Unlike some PTASes, there are no hidden galactic constants, but local search methods (2-opt, 3-opt, k-opt, Keld Helsgaun's excellent LKH) are simpler and unreasonably effective in practice, and branch and bound methods (usually based on the Held--Karp LP) give exact answers on surprisingly large Euclidean planar instances. Evolutionary algorithms probably are not worth consideration.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Well you clearly have a better overview over the available approximation schemes, so please feel free to write an answer or improve my answer through editing. I cannot make any judgement about what would work well in practice here

Comment: Sorry, I get kind of grumpy when the inevitable genetic algorithm suggestion is made.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using an evolutionary algorithm.
Look at this: http://johnnewcombe.net/blog/post/23

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion, i was just trying to find a simpler way to implement this. Using such an algorithm seems to take much longer development time than having a heuristic solution or something like that, somehow i can do performance sacrificies in order to keep the implementation simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at TPL (Task Parallel Library) to speed up the application.

**EDIT**

I found this **Link** which has a Traveling Salesman algorithm:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg983491.aspx

The **Source Code** is said to be at:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mag201104BeeColony

Comment: First i have to have the right algorithm and then, these speed up things will came :).

Comment: I'm not that strong in math, but if you just have a random set of points not generated from an equation then I think you will need to have a good reference to help you find the best solution.  In College we studied this and the book I used was Algorithms and Data Structures: Niklaus Wirth.  If I remember correclty, this book had algorithms written in pascal, which would be easy to convert to c#

Comment: The points are randomly generated, first i was just trying to find just a "geometrical" solution, to keep the things simpler. For me it is easyer to mantain and understand code which is entirely written by me. Somehow i think thay this speeding up the development time, but yes... if converting an existing algoritm will be the last solution i will have to do it like that. Thank you for your algorithms suggestions !